# How do listen rest api with websocket client

Tags: java, websocket

Basically i want to listen my rest api calls. Like when somebody is sending data to my rest api. (ex: http://localhost:8080/api/people) Then websocket client listen and can get response from that address, if somebody is call that address. (like when you use postman to get response from rest api then websocet client can listen that response to.). I am littlebit lost, i dont know how to listen my rest api with websocket client. i have tried "java Socket" but then i get connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException error. Any suggestions or example how do create that websocket client that can listen rest api? Websocken client have to be  simple java program that can be run from cmd.

Comment: why do you want to use socket? you can use http instead. maybe you want socket with some path variable and sub url? like ws://mysite.com/endpoint/student if you want this use web socket instead of rest you can read more about [web socket here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/websocket002.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `javax.websocket` and implement an endpoint. you can then connect to this endpoint. when you connect, you can save your session as well in a synchronized way (`CopyonWriteList<T>` for example). When your REST API is called, you can access the list of WebSocket sessions and send the data you want to return as your response of REST API back to the WebSocket client. I don't know what framework you are using, but you can also use aspects.